# Upgrading ASP.Net Core Angular 2 app from Angular 2 to Angular4

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have created an Angular SPA application using the templates from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates` (.Net Core 1.1 and Angular 2). I am trying to upgrade this project to Angular4 following the instructions from [here](http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html).

After upgrading if I try to run the app I am getting this error

[image: Call to node module failed with error]

I have changed this:

```
import { UniversalModule } from 'angular2-universal
```

to this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

As the UniversalModule is now part of platform-browser, are there any changes required to the files generated by dotnet spa template?

As I have removed angular2-universal from the project I am receiving errors at some places. for example, in boot-client.ts:
`import { platformUniversalDynamic } from 'angular2-universal';`

where is `platformUniversalDynamic` located now? Also, should I remove all the references to 'angular2-universal-polyfills/browser' and similar references?

Here are my dependencies section from packages.json

```
"dependencies": {
   "@angular/animations": "^4.0.2",
   "@angular/common": "^4.0.2",
   "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.2",
   "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.2",
   "@angular/core": "^4.0.2",
   "@angular/forms": "^4.0.2",
   "@angular/http": "^4.0.2",
   "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.2",
   "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.2",
   "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.2",
   "@angular/router": "^4.0.2",
   "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
   "aspnet-prerendering": "^2.0.0",
   "aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.17",
   "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0",
   "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
   "css": "^2.2.1",
   "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
   "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
   "event-source-polyfill": "^0.0.7",
   "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
   "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc",
   "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
   "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
   "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
   "jquery": "^2.2.1",
   "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
   "preboot": "^4.5.2",
   "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
   "rxjs": "^5.3.0",
   "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
   "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
   "typescript": "^2.2.2",
   "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
   "webpack": "^2.2.0",
   "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2",
   "webpack-merge": "^0.14.1",
   "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
 }
```

Comment: I found this after posting this question here. Seems upgrading existing one is trcky. Watch this thread if you are in the same boat as me https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/800